# Are there any good references on "inner chain complexes", chain complexes that are somehow endowed with a bilinear pairing?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Define an "inner chain complex" to be a chain complex $C_\bullet$ over a ring $R$ equipped with a chain map $C_\bullet \otimes C_\bullet \to R$, where $R$ is regarded as a chain complex in the usual way. This map is supposed to be an "inner product" of sorts for $C_\bullet$, which could be used to think about the "transpose" of the boundary maps.

I have no idea what a map of inner chain complexes should be, though. I've looked for literature on these objects, but I haven't found any which attempts to construct a reasonable category for them. To my knowledge, there isn't a good category of inner product spaces (not just Hilbert spaces) with morphisms that aren't just arbitrary linear maps. Does literature exist for this sort of object, in particular in a categorical setting?

Comment: You could look at Ranicki's "Algebraic theory of surgery"

Comment: What is wrong with definining a morphism from $(C,\beta)$ to $(C',\beta')$ to be a morphism $f : C \to C$' such that $\beta' \circ (f \otimes f) = \beta$? These may be seen as linear isometries.